# Uploadcare object saving only uuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, uploadcare

I am using the gem "uploadcare-rails", ">= 0.1.0" https://github.com/mouseed/uploadcare-rails  in my Rails application for uploading images. After file upload it assigns uuid to value of the image column. It only save the uuid in the image column and doesn't save any other information like record.image.url, record.image.size or record.image.image?

I am currently on free plan. Does it provide all the file info on free plan or is there any thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use [this gem](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-rails) instead.

Second, file info provided by Uploadcare API does not depend on a plan you're using.

It seems that info is being saved to [`file.data`](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-ruby/blob/master/lib/uploadcare/resources/file.rb) property, but is not publicly available. You may want to patch it in and send a PR :)